# Java - generate compartments / intervals from min, max and count

Tags: java, math, numbers, range, intervals

I need to generate values for a legend on a map based by giving an array of values. 
Is there a function in any Java library that would me generate range or compartments from array of values and a count value? Something like:

```
Integer[] getIntervals(Number[] values , int count);
```

Example usage:

`getIntervals([10, 33.5, 45.98, 62, 77,80 ], 5)` would return `[10, 24, 38, 52, 64, 80]`

This is easy to write by myself but it has to do it smart to show it nice on legend a map. By smart i mean to generate number that make sense on a legend. I dont know how to describe it in english so i attach a screenshot that shows what i mean.

If the above funtion would be smart the way i want it it would return:
`[10, 30, 50, 70, 90]` or something like that.

[image]

This is still something i could write myself, but maybe this is somewhere already done? I looked into Apache Commons MathUtils and Apache Commons Math but could not find there what i need.

**EDIT:** I found there is in Apache Commons a [Percentile](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/stat/descriptive/rank/Percentile.html) class that seems to be what i need to use but i'm too weak at math.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking about. Why is the above array not better than the bottom one? How do you define a smart method that does this? From what I understand, you want a function which generates a list of numbers, each pair of neighbors (from left to right) having a larger difference than the previous pair.

Comment: Do you want `getIntervals` to calculate the ranges to be used in the legend? Do you want the ranges to be of equal size or do you want the number of values in each range to be as even as possible?

Comment: Does something exist which meets your subjective (and undisclosed) criteria of "smartness"? Maybe, but probably not.

Answer (score 1):

Your question needs work, but I choose to read it as *"I am trying to build nicely-spaced ticks for a range of input values for visualization purposes"*. In that case, I suggest that you have a long look at [how D3.js implements such scales](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quantitative-Scales#linear_nice). Yes, Javascript is not Java -- but D3.js is a well-known visualization library, the problem you describe is a well-known visualization problem, and the syntax is similar-enough to Java to allow you to adapt the ideas quite easily.

In a nutshell, and loosely translating:

```
public interface LinearScale {
    /**
     * build a scale from min to max; see d3 linear.domain()
     * and then expand it to make it end in nice, round numbers; 
     *  see d3 linear.nice()
     */
    void setNiceDomain(double min, double max);
    /**
     * set number of threshold values; see d3 linear.ticks()
     *   and return their values
     */
    double[] setThresholdCount(int ticks);
    /**
     * gets the largest threshold that is <= a given value
     */
    double map(double value);
}
```

(JS) source-code is available at https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/src/scale/linear.js ; chosen snippets (from the implementation of `linear.ticks()`):

```
function d3_scale_linearTickRange(domain, m) {
    if (m == null) m = 10;

    var extent = d3_scaleExtent(domain),
        span = extent[1] - extent[0],
        step = Math.pow(10, Math.floor(Math.log(span / m) / Math.LN10)),
        err = m / span * step;

    // Filter ticks to get closer to the desired count.
    if (err <= .15) step *= 10;
    else if (err <= .35) step *= 5;
    else if (err <= .75) step *= 2;

    // Round start and stop values to step interval.
    extent[0] = Math.ceil(extent[0] / step) * step;
    extent[1] = Math.floor(extent[1] / step) * step + step * .5; // inclusive
    extent[2] = step;
    return extent;
}

function d3_scale_linearTicks(domain, m) {
    return d3.range.apply(d3, d3_scale_linearTickRange(domain, m));
}
```